# Diferencia al capturar el texto

Tags: javascript

¿Cuál es la diferencia a la hora de usar `.text` y `.innerHTML` para obtener el texto?

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',() => {
var pattern = /^joya[0-9]/,
    getting = document.getElementsByTagName('*'),
    elements = [];
    Array.from(getting).forEach(clase => {
     if(pattern.test(clase.className)) elements.push(clase);
    });
    
    /* Mostrar */
    
    elements.forEach(i => {  /* .text */
     console.log('Con .text: ' + i.text);
    });
    elements.forEach(i => { /* .innerHTML */
     console.log('Con innerHTML: ' + i.innerHTML);
    });
    
    
});
```

```html
<a class='joya1' href='' value="joyita1">joyyy1</a>
<a class='joya2' href='' value="joyita2">joyyy2</a>
<a class='joya3' href='' value="joyita3">joyyy3</a>
```

Comment: innerHTML te devuelve todo el HTML dentro de la etiqueta (si solo hay texto, pues el texto) y text te devuelve el texto de las etiquetas de texto! no todas las etiquetas son validas con text. Te dejo un [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent#Differences_from_innerText) a la docu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aunque los resultados van a ser parecidos en algunos casos, no lo van a ser en todos (como bien indica [Asier en su respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/104786/250)). Ahora, hay más diferencias que sólo las que se indican ahí.

Voy a aprovechar para introducir dos más que no aparecen en la pregunta, pero que son relevantes para este caso: [`.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) e [`.innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Node/innerText) (existe un `.outerText` pero no es estándar).

Para que funciona cada uno de ellos:

- `.innerHTML` devuelve texto y código (en forma de texto), es decir te va a devolver las etiquetas y el texto contenido en ellas.
- `.innerText` devuelve sólo el texto renderizado. La parte clave es "renderizado". Eso quiere decir que sólo se mostrará el texto que el navegador puede mostrar (p.e. si hay un `script` el código de dentro no se mostrará como texto).
- `.textContent` devuelve sólo el texto. Y es importante identificar que por texto en este caso nos referimos a todo el texto contenido (p.e. si hay un `script`, el código se mostrará como texto aunque no sea visible en la página).
- `.text` funciona como una versión corta de sólo lectura de `.textContent`... aunque lo de "sólo lectura" no es algo que los navegadores impongan. Además, **su comportamiento va a cambiar dependiendo del elemento en el que se utilice y se considera obsoleto para algunos elementos**.

Vamos a ver un ejemplo con esas cuatro funciones en el elemento `body` (uno de los que difiere y que [se considera obsoleto desde HTML 5](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html#attr-body-text)):

```js
var miBody = document.getElementById("miBody");

console.log(miBody.innerHTML);
console.log(miBody.textContent);
console.log(miBody.text);
console.log(miBody.innerText);
```

```html
<body id="miBody">
  <a href="miA" href="http://es.stackoverflow.com">Soy un enlace</a>
  <script id="miScript">
  var variable = 1;
  </script>
  Texto suelto
</body>
```

¿Por qué devuelve una cadena vacía para `.text`? Dato interesante: en versiones anteriores de HTML, el atributo `text` en el `body` servía para cambiar el color de la fuente, aunque esa funcionalidad se considera obsoleta desde hace años, los navegadores la siguen utilizando. Por ejemplo, si haces `miBody.text = "#ff0000";` esperarías que el texto de la página cambiara a #ff0000, ¿no? ¡No! El color del texto cambiará a rojo:

```js
var miBody = document.getElementById("miBody");

miBody.text = "#ff0000";
```

```html
<body id="miBody">
  <a href="miA" href="http://es.stackoverflow.com">Soy un enlace</a>
  <script id="miScript">
  var variable = 1;
  </script>
  Texto suelto
</body>
```

Es un ejemplo de un atributo que debería funcionar de un modo, pero los navegadores lo usan de otro diferente. En lugar de usar `.text` deberías usar `.innerText` o `.textContent`, que son estándar y soportados por todos los navegadores modernos.

Answer (score 8):

En un caso te devuelve el texto que se muestra (`text`) y en el otro el código HTML (`innerHTML`).

En tu ejemplo coinciden, pero si lo modificas un poco podrás ver la diferencia:

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',() => {
var pattern = /^joya[0-9]/,
    getting = document.getElementsByTagName('*'),
    elements = [];
    Array.from(getting).forEach(clase => {
     if(pattern.test(clase.className)) elements.push(clase);
    });
    
    /* Mostrar */
    
    elements.forEach(i => {  /* .text */
     console.log('Con .text: ' + i.text);
    });
    elements.forEach(i => { /* .innerHTML */
     console.log('Con innerHTML: ' + i.innerHTML);
    });
    
    
});
```

```html
<a class='joya1' href='' value="joyita1"><b>joyyy1</b></a>
<a class='joya2' href='' value="joyita2"><i>joyyy2</i></a>
<a class='joya3' href='' value="joyita3">joyyy3</a>
```

Comment: No me sabía eso, gracias Asier